# Changing the gradient color of `shap.summary_plot()` to specific 2 or 3 RGB gradient palette Colors

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, color-palette, shap

I have been trying to change the gradient palette colours from the `shap.summary_plot()` to the ones interested, exemplified in RGB.

To illustrate it, I have tried to use matplotlib to create my palette. However, it has not worked so far.
Could someone help me with that ?

This is what I have tried so far:
Creating an example with the `iris` dataset (No problem in here)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import xgboost as xgb
import shap

# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
Y = pd.DataFrame(iris.target, columns = ["Species"])
X = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns = iris.feature_names)


X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0, stratify=Y)

params = { # General Parameters
            'booster': 'gbtree',
            # Param for boosting
             'eta': 0.2, 
             'gamma': 1,
             'max_depth': 5,
             'min_child_weight': 5,
             'subsample': 0.5,
             'colsample_bynode': 0.5,             
             'lambda': 0,  #default = 0                                        
             'alpha': 1,    #default = 1            
            # Command line parameters
             'num_rounds': 10000,
            # Learning Task Parameters
             'objective': 'multi:softprob' #'multi:softprob'
             }


model = xgb.XGBClassifier(**params, verbose=0, cv=5 , )
# fitting the model
model.fit(X_train,np.ravel(Y_train), eval_set=[(X_test, np.ravel(Y_test))], early_stopping_rounds=20)
# Tree on XGBoost
explainerXGB = shap.TreeExplainer(model, data=X, model_output ="margin")
#recall one  can put "probablity"  then we explain the output of the model transformed 
#into probability space (note that this means the SHAP values now sum to the probability output of the model).
shap_values_XGB_test = explainerXGB.shap_values(X_test)
shap_values_XGB_train = explainerXGB.shap_values(X_train)

shap.summary_plot(shap_values_XGB_train, X_train, )#color=cmap
```

Until here if you run the code when should get the summary plot with the default colors. In order to change the default ones, I have tried to create my 2 color gradient palette as following:

```
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap

RGB_val = 255

color01= (0,150,200)  # Blue wanted
color04= (220,60,60)  # red wanted
Colors = [color01, color04]

# Creating a blue red palette transition for graphics
Colors= [(R/RGB_val,G/RGB_val,B/RGB_val) for idx, (R,G,B) in enumerate(Colors)]
n = 256

# Start of the creation of the gradient
Color01= ListedColormap(Colors[0], name='Color01', N=None)
Color04= ListedColormap(Colors[1], name='Color04', N=None)
top = cm.get_cmap(Color01,128)
bottom = cm.get_cmap(Color04,128)
newcolors = np.vstack((top(np.linspace(0, 1, 128)),
                       bottom(np.linspace(0, 1, 128))))

mymin0 = newcolors[0][0]
mymin1 = newcolors[0][1]
mymin2 = newcolors[0][2]
mymin3 = newcolors[0][3]
mymax0 = newcolors[255][0]
mymax1 = newcolors[255][1]
mymax2 = newcolors[255][2]
mymax3 = newcolors[255][3]

GradientBlueRed= [np.linspace(mymin0, mymax0,  n),
                   np.linspace(mymin1, mymax1,  n),
                   np.linspace(mymin2, mymax2,  n),
                   np.linspace(mymin3, mymax3,  n)]

GradientBlueRed_res =np.transpose(GradientBlueRed)

# End of the creation of the gradient

newcmp = ListedColormap(GradientBlueRed_res, name='BlueRed')

shap.summary_plot(shap_values_XGB_train, X_train, color=newcmp)
```

But I haven't been able to get a change on the colors of the graphic. :

[image]

Can someone explain me how to make it for:

(A) 2 gradient color or
(B) 3 color gradient (specifying a color in the middle between the other 2) ?

Thank you so much for your time in advanced,

Comment: What exactly are you expecting? Did you have a look at seaborn's color palettes?  https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html

Comment: No, I did not, I am gonna check it now. Thanks. What I checked was https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html, but I could not get myself through it

Comment: I don't really understand if your problem is creating the colormap or displaying something on your plot. Would be glad to help.

Comment: My only problem is being able to create a cmap to pass in the `color=` argument of the function `shap.summary_plot(shap_values_XGB_train, X_train, color=newcmp)` such that the palette is defined as RGB Colors: (1) 2 gradient colors (i.e. from color01= (0,150,200) to color04= (220,60,60) ) to provide that in and (2)  3 gradient colors (i.e. from color01= (0,150,200) to color02 =(0,0,0) to color04= (220,60,60)) . Feel free to edit my question such that is more clear to be searched for :).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I tried something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already shown [here](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/62), my workaround solution using the set_cmap() function of figure's artists:

```
# Create colormap
newcmp = ListedColormap(GradientBlueRed_res, name='BlueRed')

# Plot the summary without showing it
plt.figure()
shap.summary_plot(shap_values_XGB_train, X_train, show=False)

# Change the colormap of the artists
for fc in plt.gcf().get_children():
    for fcc in fc.get_children():
        if hasattr(fcc, "set_cmap"):
            fcc.set_cmap(newcmp)
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUjKs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I made it a solution for this SHAP plot (**currently version is 0.39**). Basically you can generate a cmap and then use it through the parameter `cmap`.

An example:

```py
import shap
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

# Generate colormap through matplotlib
newCmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ['#c4cfd4','#3345ea'])

# Set plot
shap.decision_plot(..., plot_color=newCmap)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which version of SHAP you are using, but in version 0.4.0 (02-2022) summary plot has cmap parameter, so you can directly pass the cmap you build to it:

```
    shap.summary_plot(shap_values, plot_type='dot', plot_size=(12, 6), cmap='hsv')
```